# Problems hiding /.git repository on nginx webserver?

Tags: git, nginx

Its come to our attention that an old website we run has an exposed /.git repository.  After reading a few other posts, I've added:

```
location ~ /\.git {
     deny all;
}
```

...to my configuration file.  And when I run 'Get Git' or 'Bishop' extensions in Chrome, I can see the following in the error log:

> 2016/05/24 18:10:34 [error] 26922#0: *6 access forbidden by rule, client: 127.0.0.1, server: *#websiteremoved#*.com, request: "GET /.git HTTP/1.1"

So, it looks like the rule is working?  But the 'Get Git' and 'Bishop' extensions are still flagging them as vulnerable?  Am I still doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep your .git directory somewhere else and just have the working tree in the publicly visible path. For this read the section about `core.worktree` in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config